# Logarithmic score decay based on time

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm looking for an algorithm that has a score that logarithmically gets smaller over time. This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771670/algorithmic-scoring-based-on-time) but the algorithm should have a nice curve instead of being linear. A time of 1 should have a score of 1, with the score diminishing as the time value increases and ideally there would be a configurable value where the score become crosses the X axis and becomes 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function satisfies your criteria

```
score(t) = -A log(t) + 1

where A > 0
```

The score crosses the X-axis at

```
T = exp(1/A)
```